# Picewise Transformation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image, affinetransform, piecewise

I am looking for a function that can uses all the transformation matrix of PiecewiseAffineTransform to apply on the source data to get the destination data at one run. I could use piecewise transformation and I could not find the function for using all the transformation matrix at same time, this code can use all transformation matrix in a loop which is not the right way that should be done ,I also present all the functions of the estimated transformation matrix in the skimage package

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from skimage.transform import PiecewiseAffineTransform
src = np.array([0,0 , 1,0 , 1,1 , 0,1]).reshape((4, 2))
dst = np.array([3,1 , 3,2 , 2,2 , 2,1]).reshape((4, 2))
tform = tf.estimate_transform('piecewise-affine', src, dst)
print(src)
print(dst)
print(tform.affines[0].params)
print(tform.affines[1].params)
mt = tf.matrix_transform(src, tform.affines[0].params)
print(mt)



>>> dir(tform)
['__add__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_inverse_tesselation', '_tesselation', 'affines', 'estimate', 'inverse', 'inverse_affines', 'residuals']
```

Comment: *always* use the generic Python tag, and only optionally include any version-specific tags if necessary (if the question is about a specific version)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for your advice ok sure will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `tform` object with the source data as an argument (see https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_geometric.py#L871):

```
In []: src
Out[]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])

In []: tform(src)
Out[]: 
array([[ 3.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.]])
```